# why reflection.assembly loadfile doesn't load all dlls?

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

I am using LoadFrom(), to load dlls, but for some reason this load function doesn't work on all dlls,
i want to load 3000 dlls to get from each one the copyright attribute.

my code :

```
    class ReverseDLL
{
    private Assembly assembly;
    private AssemblyDescriptionAttribute desc;
    private AssemblyTitleAttribute title;
    private AssemblyCopyrightAttribute copyRight;

    public string getCopyright(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            //assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
            assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path);//"C:\\Windows\\winsxs\\x86_microsoft.vc90.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_bb1f6aa1308c35eb\\msvcm90d.dll");//path);// LoadFrom(path);

                desc = (AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)
                AssemblyDescriptionAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                assembly, typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute));

                title = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)
                AssemblyTitleAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(
                assembly, typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute));

                copyRight = (AssemblyCopyrightAttribute)AssemblyCopyrightAttribute.GetCustomAttribute(assembly, typeof(AssemblyCopyrightAttribute));
        }
        catch
        {
              this.copyRight = new AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("");
        }

        if (this.copyRight == null)
            this.copyRight = new AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("");

        return copyRight.Copyright;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all the dlls managed dlls?

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a terribly detailed diagnostic report... possibly due to you just catching all exceptions without logging anything about what's going on. (Catching *everything* like this is very *very* rarely the right thing to do.) What's the exception when it fails?

Comment: You could print out a stack trace when you catch an exception. Likely you'll see some dlls built for something else than what your program runs as (e.g. trying to load x64 dlls on x86, trying to load native dlls, not .NET assemblies, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the reflection problem without you providing more info (such as the error), but you *could* also try access the file itself:

```
string copyright = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).LegalCopyright;
```

This accesses the file-system meta-data (like you would see in explorer), and has the advantage of working for both managed and unmanaged dlls; **but** it requires that meta-data to exist (it *doesn't* look at the attribute).

Edit: a quick check indicates that (as expected) the compiler *does* check for this attribute and populate the file meta-data correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion, it's really helped a lot,
can i get also the digital signature from files?

Comment: @kimo - I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping on exceptions?  Ctrl + Alt + E, stop on framework exceptions when they are thrown.  The exception message should give you some information as to why the DLL couldn't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection is not the optimal approach, as some of the dll may have dependencies you don't have.

Using a metadata parser can give you the things you want,

http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/

http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil

The way Marc mentioned does not work for most .NET specific metadata.